# Formatting parameters in different lines using editor config

Tags: editorconfig

Is there any way to use editor config to format parameters in different lines.

- Example 1 violates the guideline.
- Example 2 has more than 3 parameters.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's it.

```
max_line_length=120

csharp_wrap_after_declaration_lpar=true
csharp_wrap_parameters_style=chop_if_long
csharp_max_formal_parameters_on_line=3

csharp_wrap_after_invocation_lpar=true
csharp_wrap_arguments_style=chop_if_long
csharp_max_invocation_arguments_on_line=3
```